# Cannot install ruby 1.9.3 using RVM. Seems to be some type of git error

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

When I execute `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-head` I get this error:

```
➜  ~  rvm install ruby-1.9.3-head
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Branch origin/ruby_1_9_3 not found.
There has been an error while checking out branch ruby_1_9_3.  
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.

ruby-1.9.3-head is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-head'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I recently installed ruby 1.9.3 via rvm, but I simply used `rvm install ruby-1.9.3`. RVM will install `ruby-1.9.3p286` using that command.

Comment: The higher-scoring answer ought to be marked correct, as it's a more direct solution. "Reinstall the OS" might work too, but it's not the right way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem and it seemed that some repository data was out of date/broken.

`➜ rvm cleanup repos` took care of this and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do `rvm get stable` or `rvm get head` first. You might have an outdated version of RVM.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to fix the problem.